# Is it possible to format dateComponent to display as hh:mm:ss?

Tags: ios, swift, date, time, nsdate

I'm trying to display a countdown in a hh:mm:ss format but since I'm not outputting the Date but the dateComponents, I can't use formatter.dateFormat. Is there a possibility to format the dateComponents?

Currently I get an output that looks like this:

Hour: 5, Minute: 12, Second: 45

```
func nextEventCalculator() -> DateComponents {
    let now = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, hour: 12, minute: 15)  // <- 12:15 pm
    let nextEvent = calendar.nextDate(after: now, matching: components, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!

    let diff = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: now, to: nextEvent)
    dateCountdownLabel.text = "\(diff)"
    return diff
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DateComponentsFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter) with a [`unitsStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter/1413441-unitsstyle) of `.positional`:

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
dateCountdownLabel.text = formatter.string(from: diff)
```